# What type does razor @helper return?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Cat I create a delegate on @helper function?

```
@helper DisplayCategoryTree(int? parentId)
{       

   Func<Category, CategoryNode, MvcHtmlString> act = new Func<Category, CategoryNode, MvcHtmlString>(GetChildItem);
   act(Category, CategoryNode);

}

@helper GetChildItem(Category, CategoryNode)
{     


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The razor helpers are returning [System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.helperresult%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) which implements `IHtmlString` so you can use that instead of `MvcHtmlString`.

So this declaration should work fine:

```
@helper DisplayCategoryTree(int? parentId)
{       

   Func<Category, CategoryNode, IHtmlString> act = 
       new Func<Category, CategoryNode, IHtmlString>(GetChildItem);
   act(Category, CategoryNode);
}

@helper GetChildItem(Category, CategoryNode)
{    
}
```

Comment: I would like to add that I have written an in depth article about HTML Helpers that will teach you almost everything about them. http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/writing-custom-html-helpers-for-asp.net-mvc/